# How do you remove a module with Yeoman?

Tags: yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm using Yeoman `generator-cg-angular` to create my Angular Project.

They have a convenient way to create new modules, but they don't specify how you could remove a module.

I just create a module but I wrote the wrong name. I was going to delete the module I created but there are so many other locations that were automatically written with this name. So I'm wondering, is there a proper way to delete the module that will automatically remove everything?

Answer (score 1):

Usually Yeoman doesn't provide ways to undo commands.

This is because tracking a project history is usually done using a tool like [git](https://git-scm.com/) or svn.

Provided you commit your code often, you then only need to run `git reset --hard` (or/and `git clean -f` for untracked directories) and it'll reset the code to your last history state.

If you don't know any of these tools, then I strongly suggest you to take the time to learn them. They're essential tools to the everyday life of any programmer.